# Using ByteArrayInputStream in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring Webflux to recieve files (DICOM) and a library that converts those files to Json strings (DCM4CHE).
This library take an InputStream in entry for the conversion.
I thought using a ByteArrayInputStream to keep the stack reactive. Is that correct or do I need to wrap the call in a Mono.defer(...) or to use a non reactive microservice?

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> toJson(ServerRequest request) {
    var flux = request.body(BodyExtractors.toParts())
            .ofType(FilePart.class)
            .map(FilePart::content)
            .flatMap(DataBufferUtils::join)
            .map(DataBuffer::asByteBuffer)
            .map(ByteBuffer::array)
            .map(ByteArrayInputStream::new)
            .map(theLib::convertToJson);
    return ServerResponse.ok().body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(flux,String.class));
}
```

In another words, Is the ByteArrayInputStream somehow a blocking code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, ByteArrayInputStream is not blocking. The only method which could potentially block is `long transferTo(OutputStream out)` if the `OutputStream out` were blocking.

By the way, instead of

```
    .map(DataBuffer::asByteBuffer)
    .map(ByteBuffer::array)
    .map(ByteArrayInputStream::new)
```

you could write

```
    .map(DataBuffer::asInputStream)
```

Comment: Surprisingly, the InputStream instance produced by the asInputStreamMethod can't be used by the lib.